# react-virtualized - Keep scroll position between components with InfiniteLoader/WindowScroller/List/CellMeasurer

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, react-virtualized

I'm using `react-virtualized` package and so far it's working great.
Just couldn't find the way to restore scroll position when the path changes and back to the page.

Tried to use `scrollToPosition` provided by `List` or keep scroll positionY in global state and window.scrollTo in useEffect but it's not navigating to the list position as expected.

I'm using `<InfiniteLoader>`, `<WindowScroller>`, `<List>` and `<CellMeasurer>`.
Code looks like below.

```js
...
const cache = new CellMeasurerCache({
  defaultHeight: 900,
  fixedWidth: true,
})
....

const App = () => {

  const getData = useGetData() // api call
  const setPosition = useSetScrollPosition()

  const data = useRecoilValue(getTimeline)
  const hasMore = useRecoilValue(hasMore) // Global state
  const loading = useRecoilValue(loadingData) // Global state
  const positionY = useRecoilValue(scrollPosition) // Global state
 
  const infiniteScrollRef = useRef()
  const listRef = useRef()

  const innerWidth = window.innerWidth
  const cardWidth = innerWidth > 640 ? 640 : innerWidth


  useEffect(() => {
    if (data.length === 0) {
      // API call
    }
    return () => {
      // Set pageY offset when you leave
      const position = window.pageYOffset
      setPosition(position)
    }
  }, [])

  const addMore = () => {
    // API call
  }

  // HERE: trying to restore scroll position!
  useEffect(() => {
    if (listRef.current && positionY !== 0) {
      listRef.current.scrollToPosition(positionY)
    }
  }, [positionY])

  useEffect(() => {
    resizeRowRenderer(data.length)
   }, [data && data.length])

  const resizeRowRenderer = useCallback(
    index => {
      cache.clear(index, 0)
      if (listRef.current) {
        listRef.current.recomputeRowHeights(index)
      }
    },
    [data]
  )

  const isRowLoaded = useCallback(
    ({ index }) => {
      return !!data[index]
    },
    [data.length]
  )

  const infiniteRowCount = useCallback(() => {
    return !loading && hasMore ? data.length + 1 : data.length
  }, [loading, hasMore])

  const listRowCount = useCallback(() => {
    return hasMore ? data.length + 1 : data.length
  }, [data])

  const rowRenderer = useCallback(
    ({ index, key, parent, style }) => {
      return (
        <CellMeasurer
          cache={cache}
          columnIndex={0}
          key={key}
          parent={parent}
          rowIndex={index}
        >
          {({ measure }) => (
            <div style={style}>
              {isRowLoaded({ index }) ? (
                <div style={{ margin: '8px 0' }}>
                  <Card
                    measure={measure}
                    data={data[index]}
                  />
                </div>
              ) : (
                <div>
                  <CircularProgress />
                </div>
              )}
            </div>
          )}
        </CellMeasurer>
      )
    },
    [data, isRowLoaded]
  )

  return (
    <Wrapper>
      <InfiniteLoader
        isRowLoaded={isRowLoaded}
        loadMoreRows={addMore}
        ref={el => (infiniteScrollRef.current = el)}
        rowCount={infiniteRowCount()}
        threshold={1}
        minimumBatchSize={1}
      >
        {({ onRowsRendered, registerChild }) => (
          <WindowScroller>
            {({ height, isScrolling, onChildScroll, scrollTop }) => {
              return (
                <List
                  autoHeight={true}
                  deferredMeasurementCache={cache}
                  height={height}
                  scrollTop={scrollTop} // Not sure this should set to something else
                  isScrolling={isScrolling}
                  onRowsRendered={onRowsRendered}
                  onScroll={onChildScroll}
                  ref={el => {
                    listRef.current = el
                    registerChild(el)
                  }}
                  rowHeight={cache.rowHeight}
                  rowRenderer={rowRenderer}
                  rowCount={listRowCount()}
                  width={cardWidth}
                />
              )
            }}
          </WindowScroller>
        )}
      </InfiniteLoader>
    </Wrapper>
  )
}
export default App
```

In `<List >` component, without `scrollTop={scrollTop}` or scrollTop={someNumber},
either `<InfiniteLoader />` or `<List />` doesn't work.
Any advice is appreciated.

```
**Version**
"react": "^16.12.0",
"react-dom": "^16.12.0",
"react-virtualized": "^9.19.1"
```

Comment: Removing `autoHeight={true}` did the trick